# What is this "rough" line going vertically up the side of a print called?

Tags: print-quality

I've got this rough line going right up the center of some of my prints:

[image: Photo of rough vertical line in print]

Can anyone be kind enough to tell me what this is called?  How does one fix it?

Comment: That is the seam (the start and end) of the outer perimeter of your printing object. This has been asked and answered before. We need to look up the correct question. I'll refrain from answering and will try to find the question.

Comment: I think [this](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/15776/how-to-get-less-z-seam) may answer your question.

Comment: Yes, this would seem to be a duplicate of [How to get less Z-seam?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/15776/4762) This question should be flagged as such.